# Why does eclipse generate values-sw600dp and values-sw720dp-land

Tags: android, eclipse

Does anyone know why eclipse generates the folders "values-sw600dp" and "values-sw720dp-land" by default in an Android app?

Why does it need 720dp in landscape, but not otherwise?

It seems like I would want a values folder for 320dp, 480dp, 600dp, and 720dp. Wouldn't that cover most of my bases?

Comment: Simply erase those folders and create the one you need.

Comment: It doesn't necessarily need any of them.  At some point somebody making the eclipse plugin decided those were good defaults.  What you really need will depend on your app-  you may not need any.  Delete the ones you don't need, add the ones you do.

Comment: It just creates to let you know that you may design layouts available for such dimensions too. If you don't want them then simply delete the folders and you are still good to go.

Comment: Yeah, I do know I can just delete them. I'm just curious what the logic behind putting in those two and not others is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I recall correctly those sizes relate to common widths offered by different device sizes. In other words those widths are common transition points between device sizes.

Answer (score 1):

It create them by default as you said, just delete them and create the one you need.

Answer (score 0):

values-sw600dp : Smallest dimension is 600 dp or higher

values-sw720dp-land : Smallest dimension is 720 dp or higher, and is landscape

values-v11 : Version is 11 or higher

values-v14 : Version is 14 or higher

Priority is given to whichever matches best.

Please check http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#AlternativeResources